# How to reduce dropdown list when we select an element and use it

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a form in MS Access database and depending what the user chooses from dropdown list other fields are populated. I have a "flag" in my table (true/false) if the value from dropdown list is used.

If I use that flag in query criteria for dropdown list, the populated fields in form mentioned above become blank.

Has anybody a suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Populate the data in the form on dropdown list's after update event. Use the dropdown list value in the query instead of using flag.